# Plot from list of lists in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of csv files that is the output of a solver in space and time, so the population is given for each point in time (rows) and space (columns) for different models.

I want to read them into python to plot individual rows or individual columns from the solutions.  I cannot figure out how to do this.

3 mini csv files are (mine are much larger)

```
13,26,130
15,30,150
17,34,170
19,38,190
21,42,210
23,46,230

29,58,290
31,62,310
33,66,330
35,70,350
37,74,370
39,78,390

4,8,40
5,10,50
6,12,60
7,14,70
8,16,80
9,18,90
```

MWE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os


dataFolder = "SCRATCH/"


names = ["1","2","3"]
data = [pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dataFolder+'Book'+i+'.csv'), header=None) for i in names]

plt.plot(data[0])
plt.plot(data[0][2][:],'--')
plt.plot(data[0][:][2],'*')
```

I can plot in one direction, but I cannot plot in the other.  I tried to turn the list into an np.array using `np.array(data[0])` but had the same issue accessing individual rows/columns.

[Some example csv files can be found at this link:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5Sr_HPS2TtA7iK3FBHMLQEK1Gzex6em/view?usp=sharing)

ETA: the files are read in programatically deliberately.  Writing these out as individual lines is not a viable option.  This is a small subset of a larger piece of work.  The csv files are considerably larger than the examples.

Comment: Easy solution would be to use pandas and read the files into dataframes:
`pandas.read_csv(file)`

Comment: @JohannesSchöck I do use pandas as pd.read_csv to read in the files

Comment: You're right, please provide a dataframe and not lists as example input then. For the slicing part, see my answer or the [pandas documentation on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you read your csv files with pandas to create dataframes, you can plot like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"Book1.csv", names=["A", "B", "C"])
plt.plot(np.arange(0,data.shape[1]), data.loc[row,:].values.flatten())
```

With the value of `row` you select which row you want to plot.
If you want to plot column-wise, you need to change the indexing command (`column`is the label / column name, e.g. "A" from above example) and use the other dimension of the dataframe shape for the x-axis:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0,data.shape[0]), data.loc[:,column].values.flatten())
```

Comment: Can you explain how you get the l1, l2 etc?  I need to be able to programatically read in all the files.  I need to avoid having to write hundreds of lines of code to read in each individual csv.  Searching around the advise was to use a list comprehension.

Comment: Well you provided the lists, so I used that. If you provide a csv file or the dataframe structure, then we can look at solving that part as well.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise it was unclear that they were csv files - not part of the python code.  I have created a google drive link with some example csvs.